I want to make a Weekday Picker that will take all the space available to it according to the device
I want to make a Weekday Picker that will take all the space available to it according to the device
here is what I have done till now and I have no clue how I can make it adaptive plz give me ideas
how can i make it look better
  <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="5sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5sp"
            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/fab_1"
                android:layout_marginEnd="3sp"
                android:layout_marginStart="3sp"
                android:text="S"
                android:paddingTop="6sp"
                android:paddingBottom="6sp"
                android:paddingStart="12sp"
                android:paddingEnd="12sp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/fab_1"
                android:layout_marginEnd="3sp"
                android:layout_marginStart="3sp"
                android:text="M"
                android:paddingTop="6sp"
                android:paddingBottom="6sp"
                android:paddingStart="10sp"
                android:paddingEnd="10sp"
                />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/fab_1"
                android:layout_marginEnd="3sp"
                android:layout_marginStart="3sp"
                android:text="T"
                android:paddingTop="6sp"
                android:paddingBottom="6sp"
                android:paddingStart="12sp"
                android:paddingEnd="12sp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/fab_1"
                android:layout_marginEnd="3sp"
                android:layout_marginStart="3sp"
                android:text="W"
                android:paddingTop="6sp"
                android:paddingBottom="6sp"
                android:paddingStart="10sp"
                android:paddingEnd="10sp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/fab_1"
                android:layout_marginEnd="3sp"
                android:layout_marginStart="3sp"
                android:text="T"
                android:paddingTop="6sp"
                android:paddingBottom="6sp"
                android:paddingStart="12sp"
                android:paddingEnd="12sp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/fab_1"
                android:layout_marginEnd="3sp"
                android:layout_marginStart="3sp"
                android:text="F"
                android:paddingTop="6sp"
                android:paddingBottom="6sp"
                android:paddingStart="12sp"
                android:paddingEnd="12sp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/fab_1"
                android:layout_marginEnd="3sp"
                android:layout_marginStart="3sp"
                android:text="S"
                android:paddingTop="6sp"
                android:paddingBottom="6sp"
                android:paddingStart="12sp"
                android:paddingEnd="12sp"
                />
            

        </LinearLayout>

It looks like this

help!
It just goes out of screen if not enough width for now

Not sure if I'm missing the point, but it sounds like you just want to set the widths of the TextViews to 0dp and then set the layout_weight of each to be the same (greater than 0) value. They will then split the screen width between them. However you will either need to include the letter in a scalable drawable or change the font size if the available space is too small.

will try that now

You can use ConstraintLayout along with the Flow helper. The Flow helper is part of the ConstraintLayout 2.0 and later, and it allows for responsive layouts that adjust elements based on the available space.
app:flow_wrapMode="chain": Ensures that the items are laid out in a chain and can wrap when the screen size is too small.
app:flow_horizontalStyle="spread_inside": Distributes the items evenly within the available space.
app:flow_horizontalGap and app:flow_verticalGap: Set gaps between the items.
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp">

<androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.Flow
    android:id="@+id/flow"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:flow_wrapMode="chain"
    app:flow_horizontalStyle="spread_inside"
    app:flow_horizontalGap="3dp"
    app:flow_verticalGap="3dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sun"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/fab_1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="S"
    android:padding="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/mon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/fab_1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="M"
    android:padding="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tue"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/fab_1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="T"
    android:padding="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/wed"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/fab_1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="W"
    android:padding="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/thu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/fab_1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="T"
    android:padding="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/fri"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/fab_1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="F"
    android:padding="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sat"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/fab_1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="S"
    android:padding="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


its filling the screen but not adjecting when the screen size gets smaller and goes out of screen
